# Rails ActiveRecord: lock without reload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, locking, rails-activerecord

Can I lock an ActiveRecord object without reloading it?

```
user = User.find(1)
=> #<User id: 1, name: "Ed" ...>
user.name = "Joe"
=> "Joe"
user.lock!
=> #<User id: 1, name: "Ed" ...>
```

I could send a raw SQL "SELECT ... FOR UPDATE", but it doesn't seem too clean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding a method to `ActiveRecord::Base`:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.class_eval do
  def lock_without_reload!
    self.class.lock(true).find(id)
    true
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution built into ActiveRecord:

```rb
user = User.lock.find(1)
# SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 1 LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE
# => #<User id: 1, name: "Ed" ...>
```

Comment: If you see my answer I am doing exactly this (`.lock.find(id)`). It reads a record with a lock at one go. But my question was: I wanted to obtain a lock on a record that was *previously* loaded into a variable *without* reloading it. That's why I discard the reloaded record and just return true.

Comment: @Kombajnzbożowy I see. It certainly depends on your use case, but be very cautious with that as it opens a window to nasty race conditions. Typically if you want to lock a record to avoid other sessions from modifying it in parallel, you do also want to wait for existing sessions to commit changes and reload your record to have all data fresh.

Comment: Agree, in the end this was definitely not the best approach. But I asked this question a couple of years ago :)