# Rails ActiveRecord - get belongs_to association with lock

Tags: ruby-on-rails, locking, rails-activerecord

I would like to retrieve a belongs_to association and acquire a database lock on its object.

```
> character.team.lock!
ActiveRecord::Base -- Team Load -- { :sql => "SELECT  `teams`.* FROM `teams` WHERE `teams`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1" }
ActiveRecord::Base -- Team Load -- { :sql => "SELECT  `teams`.* FROM `teams` WHERE `teams`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE" }
```

Above runs two queries, which technically makes sense - `character.team` loads the team, then `team.lock!` selects once more with `FOR UPDATE`.

The question is - how can I make it issue only one query?

Comment: Doesn't your answer from 2016 work? https://stackoverflow.com/a/38295500/3372172. If yes, use it. If not, maybe you could remove it.

Comment: @Pablo: I could use `Team.lock(true).find(character.team_id)` that will obtain the lock. However, accessing `character.team` will issue a standard SELECT query again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can carry on a scope to the association using `ActiveRecord::Relation#scoping`:

```rb
Team.lock.scoping { character.team }
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you can't, because the .lock method will always reload the instance (issuing a second SQL load). From [the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Pessimistic.html#method-i-lock-21):

> .lock: Obtain a row lock on this record. **Reloads the record to obtain the requested lock**. Pass an SQL locking clause to append the end of the SELECT statement or pass true for “FOR UPDATE” (the default, an exclusive row lock). Returns the locked record.

Answer (score 1):

Thankfully there is a solution:

```rb
character.association(:team).scope.lock.to_a[0]
# SELECT "teams".* FROM "teams" WHERE "teams"."id" = '...' LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE
```

The only difference to the SQL query is the added `FOR UPDATE`.

May be abstracted in `ApplicationRecord` for all `belongs_to` associations:

```rb
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  
  def self.belongs_to(name, *)
    class_eval <<~RUBY
      def locked_#{name}
        association(:#{name}).scope.lock.to_a[0]
      end
    RUBY

    super
  end
end
```

Then in app code:

```rb
character.locked_team
```